# #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have been entering the following SQL statement, but it has not been turning up any results and I cannot figure out why. The error on phpMyAdmin reads:

## 1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

i want use this query for a FULLtext search:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE MATCH ( `fname`,`lname` ) AGAINST ('تست')
```

for this table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 08, 2013 at 01:25 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `smtmi`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `id` bigint(17) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` bigint(17) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `student_num` bigint(17) NOT NULL,
  `national_num` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `local_birthday` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`user`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `lname` (`lname`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fname` (`fname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;
```

how to fix it?

i use MYISAM ENGINE and jquery ajax for sending instant every character.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new index like :

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `lname` (`lname`)
```